# Gmail Addon - cannot open external links even tho they are defined in the allowlist

Tags: google-chrome, google-apps-script, safari

This started happening lately. In FireFox, the links are opening ok, but in Chrome/Safari, after a quick loading sign, nothing happens.
In the console I see an error: `Refused to execute a script because its hash, its nonce, or 'unsafe-inline' does not appear in the script-src directive of the Content Security Policy.`

Addon is written in Apps Script.

Example code that stopped working:

```
CardService.newActionResponseBuilder()
    .setOpenLink(
      CardService.newOpenLink().setUrl("https://sub.fulldomain.com/foo")
    )
    .build()
```

In the manifest:

```
...
"addOns": {
    "common": {
      "openLinkUrlPrefixes": [
        "https://sub.fulldomain.com/"
      ],
...
}
```

Based on the info in the [docs](https://developers.google.com/workspace/add-ons/concepts/gsuite-manifests#allowlisting_urls), that should have worked.
Also tried defining a wildcard `"https://*.fulldomain.com/"` and tried to define a full path. Still nothing works.

**Update**

Looks like the code that stopped working is specifically `setOnClickOpenLinkAction` that calls an action that builds the url to be open:

```
// In file X I build the card
const button = CardService.newTextButton()
    .setText("click here")
    .setTextButtonStyle(CardService.TextButtonStyle.FILLED)
    .setOnClickOpenLinkAction(
      CardService.newAction()
        .setFunctionName("openLink")
        .setParameters({ ...ourParams })
    );

// ...

// In main I have the "openLink" function
export function openLink(event): ActionResponse {
  const url = buildUrl(event.parameters);

  return CardService.newActionResponseBuilder()
    .setOpenLink(CardService.newOpenLink().setUrl(url))
    .build();
}
```

Followed this [example](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/card-service/text-button#setOnClickOpenLinkAction(Action)).

**Question**

How to make `setOnClickOpenLinkAction` work?

**Workaround**

The only workaround that worked for me, was to use `setOpenLink` directly on the button:

```
const button = CardService.newTextButton()
    .setText("click here")
    .setTextButtonStyle(CardService.TextButtonStyle.FILLED)
    .setOpenLink(CardService.newOpenLink().setUrl(url))
```

My question is still the same tho, how to make `setOnClickOpenLinkAction` work?

Comment: Can you explain what exactly our question is? Is the workaround you found suitable?

Comment: @RafaGuillermo I clarified the question. Work around is ok for now, but with `setOnClickOpenLinkAction` I could also track the actual clicks, now I can't. I added the workaround to help others stuck in same situation.

Comment: @Ihopethisishelpfultoyou the `setOpenLink` isn't working for me either in Google Chrome (Gmail addon). It works in Firefox. And it used to work in both browsers...
When I click the link, a `Refused to run the JavaScript URL because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'report-sample'` appears.

Comment: Ok, I fixed this issue replacing `setOnClickOpenLinkAction(action)`
with this `setOnClickAction(action)`